# Can we skip documents in MongoDB Map Reduce based on the values computed in reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

In `mapReduce` function of Mongo, can we skip storing a document with the `out` option.

Eg:

```
Sample Documents - animals -

{
    "type": "bird",
    "value": "10"
},
{
    "type": "fish",
    "value": "30"
},
{
    "type": "fish",
    "value": "20"
},
{
    "type": "plant",
    "value": "40"
}
```

Map reduce functions

```
function map() {
    emit(this.type, this.value);
}
function reduce(key, value) {
    var total = Array.sum(value);
    // --> IF total is less than 20 then skip
    if (total < 20) {
        // skip... Maybe something like returning null? -->  Is something like this possible?
        return;
    }

    return total;
}
db.animals.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: 'mr_test' })
```

I tried searching for a solution around this in the documentation and I wasn't able to find it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot but you can always delete documents from the out collection:

```
db.mr_test.deleteMany({ value: { $lt:20 } })
```

Comment: Overall this is not an optimal solution cause if there are millions of documents that have single record then the reduce function would not work on it creating a lot of redundant documents. 

Sources -

`MongoDB will not call the reduce function for a key that has only a single value. `

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The command should be executed after mapreduce. Reduce function should not modify any collection. You run your mapreduce, then delete documents you don't need from the out collection.

Comment: Okay. I am aware of the alternative to delete the documents once mapreduce is executed. So basically it is not possible to skip documents in the reduce function correct?

Comment: That's right. I hoped "No you cannot"  part of the answer is quite straightforward. I'm afraid I can't put it simpler.

Comment: That's okay Alex. No worries. I was actually looking for skipping the document not deleting it. Never mind. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not possible to delete a key once emitted but I guess you do not accept "no" answers.